# Using substr in JavaScript discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hey just having more issues with my embedded code:

```
case "embed":
    var arguments = message.content.split("|");
    if(arguments.length == 3){
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
        embed.substr(8)
        embed.setTitle(arguments[0]);
        embed.setDescription(arguments[1]);
        embed.setColor(arguments[2]);
        embed.setFooter("Thanks to Luke!")
        message.author.send(embed)
        message.channel.send("Sent to your DM's!")
    } else {
        message.channel.send("You need to put in the arguments! **Eg.** &embed Title Description Colour.\n ***Also If your colour isnt a #FFF000 or something simular it won't work.***");
    }
break;
```

The line `embed.substr(8)` is supposed to remove 8 characters but isnt working as expected.

Comment: [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)  _returns_ a part of the string but is _not_ supposed to remove anything from the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the datatype of "embed" variable (since you are doing other operations over it. If its your own class, and substr does a string manipulation, you need to do following in the underlying function. If it's an API function, you need to look at that.

```
embed = embed.substr(8);
```

Any string operations like this (including replace, pad etc) will return you a **new** string having the modified state, the original variable is never changed.

For any code issues, you need to do step by step debugging in browser console to check out what's being the current state of the variables. Since here substr was not working as per your thought, you should have read how it works :)